# Filter dataframe based on different conditions for each group

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

```
df <- data.frame(loc.id = rep(1:10, each = 10), 
       MG = rep(1:10,times = 10),
       x = runif(100))
```

If I want to filter the data based on multiple conditions, I could do this:

```
df %>% filter(MG > 5 & loc.id < 4)
```

However, I have a situtation where filtering conditions are different. For e.g

If `loc.id` is less than 4, only keep the `MG` 1-4

If `loc.id` is between 5 to 6, only keep the `MG` 5-8

If `loc.id` is greater than 6, only keep the MG greater than 8.

Comment: One option would be enumerating combos and left-joining: with data.table `mDT = rbindlist(list(CJ(loc.id = 1:3, MG = 1:4), CJ(5:6, 5:8), CJ(7:10, 9:10))); setDT(df)[mDT, on=names(mDT), nomatch=0]` or similarly with dplyr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not this:

`df %>% filter( (loc.id<4 & between(MG, 1,4)) | (between(loc.id, 5, 6) & between(MG, 5, 8)) | (loc.id>6 & MG>8))`

Answer (score 0):

When i need to filter a dataframe i prefer to use the function which ex:

`dfalt <- df[which(df$MG > 5 & df$loc.id < 4), ]`

That works good for me!

Comment: Thank you but this does not work for me. It only filters the dataframe where all MG > 5 and loc.id < 4